# Perform event in the paper-button inside a dom-repeat template

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have the following element:

```
<dom-module id="my-blogentry">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
        .div-general{
      </style>
    <div class="div-general">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{entries}}">
            <paper-material elevation="1" animated="true" class="paper-material-presentation">
                <div class="div-date-left">
                    <span>{{item.date}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <iron-image src$="../../images/{{item.image}}" style="width:128px; height:128px;" sizing="cover"></iron-image>
                    {{item.resume}} 
                    <paper-button id="bt_readmore" on-tap="toggle">Read More</paper-button>
                    <iron-collapse id="collapse">
                      <div>{{item.content}}</div>
                    </iron-collapse>
                </div>
            </paper-material>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-blogentry',

        ready: function() {
            this.entries = [
                {id: '1', title: ‘xxx.', date: 'Tuesday, March 8, 2016', image:'im-blogdefault.png', resume:’xxx’,content:’xxxx’}
            ];
          },

        toggle: function () {
            this.$$('#collapse').toggle();
        }
    });

</script>
```

If you could check on the element code I have an `iron-collapse` element inside the `<template dom-repeat>` and a button. My proposal is the user could tap on the button and toggle the button to open the collapse element.

The problem is that the code that I have work fine with open the first item, but when I have more items on the list and I press the second item button the first and second collapse  is open too.

I was searching other posts here in the forum and I found this:
[Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events)
This example modify the items in the model but no the DOM that it is what I need (toggle my iron-collapse element).

I'll appreciate any help on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, I assigned and the id to the iron-collapse identifier and the key is using the symbol `$` in the id attribute:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{entries}}">
            <paper-material elevation="1" animated="true" class="paper-material-presentation">
                <div class="div-date-left">
                    <span>{{item.date}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="div-entry-resume">
                    <iron-image src$="../../images/{{item.image}}" style="width:128px; height:128px;" sizing="cover"></iron-image>
                    {{item.resume}} 
                    <iron-collapse id$="collapse{{item.id}}">
                      <div>{{item.content}}</div>
                    </iron-collapse>
                    <div class="div-entry-bottom">
                        <paper-button id$="bt_readmore" on-tap="toggle">Read More</paper-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </paper-material>
        </template>
```

and the polymer function:

```
toggle: function (event, detail, sender) {
            var id = event.model.item.id;
            var selector = '#collapse' + id;
            this.$$(selector).toggle();
        }
```

Thanks to @Günter Zöchbauer for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your code all `<iron-collapse>` get the same `id="collapse"`.

You can either add some value from `entries` to the `<paper-button>` and the `<iron-collapse>` or try to get the `DomRepeatModel` from the buttons click event to find the right collapse.

Example code using an unique `id` property from `entries` (I just assumed it has one):

```
<paper-button ident$="{{entries.id}}" on-tap="toggle">Read More</paper-button>
<iron-collapse ident$="{{entried.is}}">
```

```
    toggle: function (event) {
        this.$$('[ident="' + event.target.getAttribute('ident') + '"]').toggle();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer it seems you are my save boat today and I appreciate that I will check this and I'll let you know.

Comment: I got this error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: event.target.getAttributes is not a function` this is the code that I change:`<iron-collapse ident$="{{item.id}}">
        <div>{{item.content}}</div>
      </iron-collapse>
      <div class="div-entry-bottom">
       <paper-button ident$="{{item.id}}" on-tap="toggle">Read More</paper-button>
      </div>`

Comment: thanks @Günter Zöchbauer I got the answer for the problem, I appreciate a lot your help. I'm going to put my code so it serve to help others like me.

Comment: Had an redundant `s` in `getAttributes()`. Glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: Thank you very much @GünterZöchbauer, I just did a snippet with your solution, I had to adapt a little bit.
The snippet is [here on github gist](https://gist.github.com/vtellier/c2341934ccdd47d70676b3a8e696f40c)